# jQuery not changing class or CSS in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, slideshow

I have an image slideshow, which has a small DIV on top of it for ad copy. Every time the slide changes, the ad box fades out, and a new one fades in, in a different position.

This works great in every browser but IE. All of my jQuery animations are working fine, but for some reason the box won't change position. Both .css() to change my top/left values and actually changing the class using .attr() fail in IE.

Here is the JS to change the class, and show the box. The first line simply gets the position from the filename (image-6.jpg).

```
var heroPosition = vars.currentImage.attr('src').substr(-5, 1);
switch(heroPosition) {
  case "1":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-1');
    break;
  case "2":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-2');              
    break;
  case "3":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-3');
    break;
  case "4":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-4');
    break;
  case "5":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-5');
    break;
  case "6":
    $('#hero-ad').attr('class','hero-position-6');
break;
}
$('#hero-ad').show("fold", {}, 1000);
```

The code itself was sort of hacked into the Nivo image slider.

The live site is here http://www.sugarloaf.com/slredesignlocal/index.html

Most of the JS in js/plugins.js. CSS for the positions is in css/style.css

*EDIT* I should mention that I tried using .addClass() and .removeClass() and this method also failed.

Comment: While IE sucks, these methods DO work. So clearly there is some other problem going on, not the actual addClass methods. You could also try the toggleClass(), but I doubt that will work either because the other approaches should have too. Are you getting any JS errors in the console? And what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm not seeing errors in any browser. It fails in IE 6-8, haven't tested in IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are having this problem specifically in IE because you are using `substr()` with a negative number. Check out [this post](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/javascript-negative-substr-problem-in-internet-explorer/). You should consider using `slice()` instead to get the value you're expecting.

Comment: That was the problem. Unbelievable.

Comment: Welcome to developing for IE... "60% of the time, it works _every time_."

Comment: 60%? That's pretty optimistic.

Comment: The FAR more important lesson to take away from this is not the fact that substr() doesn't work correctly in IE, but how to actually start debugging the issue. As I said in a previous comment, addClass(), removeClass(), etc. DO work in IE. The problem in your case was that they were never being called at all because of the substr() bug. You started out by assuming that they didn't work, but you should have first tried to assess if they were even being called by putting some console.log() or alert() statements in your switch cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.addClass( className )` to change css classes.

e.g.

```
$('#hero-ad').addClass('hero-position-1')
```

Depending on version of IE, `class` may not be a valid attribute.

Comment: What version if IE are you using? This works in IE7, 8 and 9: http://jsfiddle.net/F62LE/

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to replace the class and not just add new class.

```
$('#hero-ad')[0].className = 'hero-position-1';
```